# Change levelname format in logRecord

Tags: python, logging

I wonder how I can change the format of levelname in logRecoed using python's logging package.

```
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(levelname)-8s %(message)s')
```

Basically, I want to replace any log name to the first letter of the name. For example,

```
INFO -> I, 
WARNING -> W, 
ERROR -> E,
```

etc.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can use the *precision* field to set a *maximum* field width:

```
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(levelname).1s %(message)s')
```

`.1` sets the field width to at most one character, truncating the level to the first character:

```
>>> for level in ('CRITICAL', 'ERROR', 'INFO', 'WARNING', 'DEBUG'):
...     print '%(level)-.1s %(message)s' % {'level': level, 'message': 'Hello world!'}
... 
C Hello world!
E Hello world!
I Hello world!
W Hello world!
D Hello world!
```

See the [*String Formatting Operations* documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations):

> *Conversion*: `'s'`
>   *Meaning*: String (converts any Python object using `str()`).
>   *Notes*: (6)
>
> 6. [...] The precision determines the maximal number of characters used.

Comment: NICE! I didn't know .1s would do this. AWESOME!

Answer (score 16):

If you want completely different levelname then use logging.addLevelName

```
logging.addLevelName(logging.DEBUG, 'DETAILED')
logging.addLevelName(logging.INFO, 'GENERAL')
```

Comment: Thanks. Used this to shorten `WARNING` to `WARN` to keep my logs aligned nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this on as I wasn't able to find any clear mention of it, if you prefer brace style formatting, you can accomplish the same thing that @Martijn Pieters with `:.1s` within your braces. Example:

```py
formatter = Formatter("[{levelname:.1}] {message}")
...
logger.info("hello world!")
```

```
[I] hello world!
```